# Does quarkus.security.jaxrs.deny-unannotated-endpoints=true overrule @TestSecurity(authorizationEnabled = false)?

Tags: quarkus

My (REST) Tests are all annotated with io.quarkus.test.security.TestSecurity's

```
@TestSecurity(authorizationEnabled = false)
```

When adding

```
quarkus.security.jaxrs.deny-unannotated-endpoints=true
```

they all fail with a 401 (thus ignoring the authorizationEnabled flag)

Is this the intended behavior?

Comment: This sounds like an edge case. Please open an issue so we can discuss what the proper behavior should be

Comment: Done: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/19896